# select one row in each group doctrine

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine

i have a table :

```
 id | user | date
 ---+----------+------
 1 | name1 | 01-02-2020
 2 | name3 | 02-04-2020
 3 | name2 | 01-02-2020
 4 | name3 | 04-05-2020
 5 | name2 | 04-02-2020
```

i would like to group by the results by name and get only one row ( latest with date )

**excepted output:**

```
id | name | date
 ---+----------+------
 1 | name1 | 01-02-2020
 5 | name2 | 04-02-2020
 4 | name3 | 04-05-2020
```

what i have done so far :

````
        ->select('f')
        ->from('table', 'f')
        ->from('User', 'u')
        ->where('u.id = f.user')
        ->orderBy('f.date', 'DESC')
        ->getQuery(); ```
````

Comment: Try adding a Group By.

Answer (score 1):

Edit : I remove SetMaxResult

Use GroupBy, orderBy :

```
$qb = $this->createQueryBuilder('f')
->leftJoin('f.user', 'u')
->groupBy('u.name')
->orderBy('f.date', 'DESC');
```

I haven't test but it should work.